# Wrap line/text in org-mode when I re-open a file

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I run emacs 24.5 and word/line wrap works fine when I write new text. However, when I reopen an org file, the text is not wrapped. This makes it hard to read text I have written before. Is there a setting or something that I can change to fix this?

Comment: You are probably looking for `visual-line-mode`. Turn it on for all variants of Text mode: `(add-hook 'text-mode-hook #'turn-on-visual-line-mode)`.

Comment: @mutbuerger Thanks for the tip. I will try that.

Answer (score 11):

You can set the variable [`org-startup-truncated`](http://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#org-startup-truncated). Its documentation:

> Non-nil means entering Org-mode will set ‘truncate-lines’. This is
>   useful since some lines containing links can be very long and
>   uninteresting.  Also tables look terrible when wrapped.

So if we don't want to truncate lines, we need to set it to nil:

```
(setq org-startup-truncated nil)
```

After this, lines will wrap. However, this is *soft* wrapping; it doesn't insert newlines into the text, just shows the text as though it wraps. This is probably what you want; newlines in titles won't really work for other things in org.